# After updating grpc to 1.57.0, I am facing some compile error by building a python wheel on alpinelinux

Tags: python, grpc, alpine-linux, python-wheel

I am using Alpine Linux to build gRPC Python wheel for our project. I just updated gRPC version from 1.54.2 to 1.57.0, then I see the following compile error:

```
gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D_WIN32_WINNT=1536 -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX=\"Python\" -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX=\"1.57.0\" -DGPR_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1 -DGRPC_ENABLE_FORK_SUPPORT=1 -DGRPC_DO_NOT_INSTANTIATE_POSIX_POLLER=1 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS "-DPyMODINIT_FUNC=extern \"C\" __attribute__((visibility (\"default\"))) PyObject*" -DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1 -Isrc/python/grpcio -Iinclude -I. -Ithird_party/abseil-cpp -Ithird_party/address_sorting/include -Ithird_party/cares/cares/include -Ithird_party/cares -Ithird_party/cares/cares -Ithird_party/cares/config_linux -Ithird_party/re2 -Ithird_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/include -Ithird_party/upb -Isrc/core/ext/upb-generated -Isrc/core/ext/upbdefs-generated -Ithird_party/utf8_range -Ithird_party/xxhash -Ithird_party/zlib -I/opt/_internal/cpython-3.12.0rc1/include/python3.12 -c src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc -o python_build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.o -g0 -pthread
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8978114Z       src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpp: In function 'void __Pyx_Raise(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)':
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8978491Z       src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpp:129825:36: error: 'PyThreadState' {aka 'struct _ts'} has no member named 'curexc_traceback'
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8978687Z       129825 |         PyObject* tmp_tb = tstate->curexc_traceback;
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8978779Z              |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8979104Z       src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpp:129828:21: error: 'PyThreadState' {aka 'struct _ts'} has no member named 'curexc_traceback'
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8979271Z       129828 |             tstate->curexc_traceback = tb;
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8979355Z              |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8979761Z       src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpp: In function 'uint64_t __Pyx_get_tp_dict_version(PyObject*)':
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8980165Z       src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpp:5593:65: warning: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8980409Z        5593 | #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
2023-09-04T12:59:12.8980507Z             |                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can not find a way to fix it. Is there any compile flags necessary? Or do I need install a new Alpine Linux package?

Comment: Means some of your other prerequisites need to be updated as well.